# Control Selection Border in PyQT

Tags: python, widget, pyqt4

this is my first post here , I am trying to achive something in pyqt , I have a control placed in a widget and when user is selecting that control , i need a selection border something similer pyqt designer has , I am attching a image for refrenct .

Anybody has any idea how I can aachive this with pyqt ?

Thanks

[image: http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/5188/movie24.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the general method would be as follows:

1. Create a QFrame that will serve as a wrapper; pass it the widget you wish to 'select'
2. Place the wrapped widget in a layout; this will be the QFrame widget's layout.
3. Overload the functions for a mouse double-click event and a paint event, so that on selection parts of the border are painted.